# reading in a variable number of long ints on one line using strchr and strtol

Tags: c, strtol, strchr

My function is not quite done yet, but what I'm going to do is:

- To read in a string of numbers separated by spaces.
- Extract the numbers from that string.
- Convert them to long ints.
- Return the number of numbers read in.

  ```
  int input( int a, int b, long int *result_array )
  {
      int ele = 0;
      char buffer[200];
      char *start, *end;

      scanf("%[^\n]%*c", buffer );

      start = buffer;

      while( ( end = ( strchr( start, ' ' ) ) != NULL ) )
      {
          result_array = strtol( start, &end, 10 );
          ele += 1;
          start = end + 1;


      }

      return ele;
  }
  ```

It doesn't seem to work properly, I think I'm using strchr wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`strtol()` returns:

> On success, the function returns the converted integral number as a long int value.
>      If no valid conversion could be performed, a zero value is returned (0L).

you should re write your code as:

```
end = buffer;
base = 10;
long int = li;
ele = 0;
while(li=strtol (end,&end, base)){
     ele += 1;
}
return ele;
```

You don't need to explicitly use `strstr()` to locate for next integer. `strtol()` smart enough and after each conversion it locate end point to next int.

I have written an running code may be your find helpful:

```
#include <stdio.h>      /* printf */
#include <stdlib.h>     /* strtol */
int main (){
  char buffer[] = "2001 11 223   444   566";
  char * end;
  long int li;
  end =buffer;
  int base =10;
  int ele = 0;
  while(li=strtol (end, &end, base)){
     printf("%ld \n", li);
     ele += 1;
  }
  printf("\nNo of elements: %d", ele);
  return 0;
}
```

its output:

```
2001 
11 
223 
444 
566 

No of elements: 5
```

[Link to codepad](http://codepad.org/1LjLRSMn)

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Oh, so that's how the strtol function works, I completely misunderstood it. I thought the second argument was where is was supposed to stop as an input, not where it actually stopped as an output. This was perfect thank you very much indeed!

Comment: @Frey1337 Yes second argument is return from `strtol()` that's the reason in second argument `end` appeared as `&end` where as first argument is input so only `end` is sufficient! ..Let me know if you have other confusion.